# Meaning of 入って in this sentence

Tags: meaning

Vernon is complaining about being woken up again by Harry's owl and says:

> 今週に入って三回目だぞ
>   Third time this week!

What is the meaning (and pronunciation: presumably はいって) of 入って here? I would have thought 今週に三回目だぞ would have had the same meaning.

I can't make the usual meaning of "to enter" and the like make any sense here.

Comment: I guess the reason why he uses 今週に入って instead of 今週 alone is it's still too early in this week for such things to happen.

Comment: As an aside, you can't insert に as like *今週に三回目. Temporal adverbials followed by に are only allowed when the verbs need them, or infrequently as "at this week", that is, you can't mention events within the week anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an idiomatic use of 入る: You "enter" into a week (at the beginning of the week). The beginning of the week is strictly speaking often taken to be Sunday, but for the purpose of this expression probably most often means Monday. So X週に入って（から） means earliest Sunday (or Monday) of Week X, but usually is intended to mean some time (a day, a few hours) after Monday morning, basically any time that wouldn't fall under "first thing in Week X".

> 来週に入ってからやりましょう
>   Let's do it some time next week.
>   *lit.* Let's do it after entering next week.

So,

> 今週に入って三回目だぞ
>   *lit.* It's the third time after entering this week!